I dont know the set and have no instructions
Can’t find out what the set is or instructions for it. It’s a red brown and tan set with a secondary bag of just red with red transparent nibs.

Welcome to Bricks StackExchange.  Experience shows that this will go much better with a picture.  Can you upload a picture of the parts you have?
